# Creating array in one line

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a code

```
 String ejgStr[] = new String[][]{{null},new String[]{"a","b","c"},{new String()}}[0] ;
 System.out.println(ejgStr[0]);
```

which compiles without error.
From what I understand you can't create an array with non-matching square brackets.

On the left, we have String ejgStr[], which is 1-d array and

On the right, we have String[][]{some array}[0], which is 2-d array

These seem to have different dimensions but why do they successfully compile?

Comment: Better use `String[] ejgStr =`. The other allowed notation was added for compatibility with C/C++, and is a dead giveaway of a novice or C/C++ programmer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a one-dimensional `String[]` array to the first dimension of an inline two-dimensional `String[][]` array.  Have a look the comments:

```
String ejgStr[] =
    new String[][] {
                     { null },                   // a null 1D String array
                     new String[] {"a","b","c"}, // a 1D String array containing a,b,c
                     { new String() }            // a String array containing empty String
                   }[0];                         // access the { null } 1D array
```

I expect your assignment to be equivalent to doing this:

```
String ejgStr[] = { null };
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign a 1D array to the ejgStr refference. If you look at the end of the first statemend, you will see that you have a `[0]` index specified which means you will assign the first array (position 0) to your referrence. If you remove the `[0]` you will receive a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

`new String[][]{...}` is a 2D array.
`new String[][]{...}[0]` is the first element of a 2D array, which is a 1D array.
That's what you're assigning to `String ejgStr[]`.

Answer (score -1):

`String ejgStr[]` is just a `reference` to a `variable` in `heap space`.
you're pointing to first dimensional of 2D-dimensional array using `[0]` and make a reference of it in `ejgStr[]`. this is not common to get 1D from 2D array, but you can do it if you need and of course it wont make compile error.